# Trying to set up an english language based Pi, located in the Netherlands, using Dutch number/date/time formats

Tags: raspbian

I fail to set my Pi to english language while located in the Netherlands, hoping to use Dutch number/date/time formats and Dutch legal Wifi-band settings. 
Raspi-config does not offer such choice.
As a compromise I chose Country NL (Netherlands), language nds (Low Saxon) as that kind of seems to have most system words in English but my wastebin is called Papierkörv.....
Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: your question is about Linux, not about RPi ...... try researching at Linux sites .... start with Debian

Comment: @jsotola it’s possible this is a raspbian specific question.

Comment: Indeed, question is related to raspbian (raspi-setup was mentioned in the question). I did not know this forum addresses rpi hardware and interfaces to it only.

Comment: all I am saying is that you have a much better chance of finding an answer if you do not limit your search to the RPi ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.. not really a question belonging to Raspberry Pi. But here a short answer because I can't put it into a comment. I manage "mixed" locale settings by its environment variables, e.g. in `~/.bashrc`. For my special German settings I use:

```
rpi ~$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```